# UberMenu Javascript API functions.

Tags: jquery, wordpress, api, megamenu

so Here is my soltuion to trigger dropdown menu when the doc is ready: it works but I can't get it to work in WP with my unbermenu plugin...help

code in jsfiddle:< http://jsfiddle.net/IMAGINEUX/AQrNs/4/ >

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#menu-item-156').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
});

$('#menu-item-156').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

after looking at UberMenu Javascript API functions:

I changed it to this;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(‘#menu - item - 156′).mouseover(function () {
    uberMenu_openMega(‘#menu - item - 15′);
});
$(‘#menu - item - 156′).trigger(‘mouseover’);
});
```

I feel like this has to be one of the simplest tasks you can do and I am going insane trying.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your HTML.  You have a typo in the JS fiddle (which the fiddle highlighted, starting in red).  Line 5 should be:

```
<li id='menu-item-156'><a href="#">About Us</a>
```

(added the ' before menu-item-156)

And there is an extra

```
  </li>
</ul>
```

at the end of the code.

Fixing that, you don't actually need to have any jQuery; the menu works on the CSS alone.  Unless I am mistaking your final results intention.

Please see this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/AQrNs/5/

Comment: The minor errors in the code do not effect the intent: which is to trigger menu by document.ready:  my trouble comes by way of implementing on a desired page with respect to the ubermenu plugin